# How to Remove "\\\" form image tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the combination of three backward slashes from Image tag.

For Example:

```
<img src=\\\"https://some-image-url\\\">
```

As you can see in 'src' there are three backward slashes in starting and in at end there is three backward slashes.
How can I removed it.
Expected:

```
<img src="https://some-image-url">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using below regex.

```js
let str = '<img src=\\\"https://some-image-url\\\">';
console.log(str.replace(/\\/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const regex = /\\+"/gm;
const str = `<img src=\\\\\\"https://some-image-url\\\\\\">`;
const subst = `"`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```